# Network card wifi not working

Tags: wireless, networking, broadcom

My wifi is not working and I have a Compaq Presario C500 and my network card is a Realtek RTL8139/810x family fast Ethernet and Broadcom 802.11b/g WLAN.

UPDATE:

`lspci -nnk | grep 14e4` says

`06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)`

and from

`lsmod | grep -e wl -e b43`says

```
b43 356470 0 
bcma 42043 1 b43 
mac80211 546051 1 b43 
cfg80211 409394 2 b43,mac80211 ssb 51854 2 b43,ssb_hcd `
```

Comment: Please add some info to your question, from terminal the results of `lspci -nnk | grep 14e4` and `lsmod | grep -e wl -e b43`

Comment: from lspci -nnk | grep 14e4 it says 06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01) and from lsmod | grep -e wl -e b43 it says

Comment: b43 356470 0
bcma 42043 1 b43
mac80211 546051 1 b43
cfg80211 409394 2 b43,mac80211
ssb 51854 2 b43,ssb_hcd
@Jeremy31

Answer (score 0):

You should just need to `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer` and reboot

Comment: Can you change the tag from realtek to broadcom?

Comment: one more thing will my wireless button still work? @Jeremy31

Comment: It should, all the command did was install firmware that the b43 driver needed to work

Comment: i cant get it to work @Jeremy31

Comment: What does `rfkill list all` show?

Comment: It shows nothing @Jeremy31

Comment: How about the results of `cat /etc/modprobe.d/* | grep b43`

Comment: It shows blacklist b43 Blacklist b43legacy #replaced by b43 and and ssb and all b43 are in red @Jeremy31

Comment: Now to figure out what file `for f in /etc/modprobe.d/*; do echo $f; cat $f | grep b43; done` and paste results into your question

Comment: ok hi so now i have lubuntu running on the computer would that make a difference from what i have to do? and do i type everything in gray to the terminal? Thank You! @Jeremy31

Comment: My answer should work on Ubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Linux Mint and any other Ubuntu derivatives that use apt-get